# Checking environment variable in make through automake

Tags: makefile, environment-variables, autotools, automake

Is there a way to have a conditional passed through automake so it is passed on to the resulting Makefile.in and Makefile later on?

I check whether JAVA_HOME is defined in the environment in a Makefile using

```
ifeq (undefined,$(origin JAVA_HOME))
#CALL with defaults
else
#CALL according to the variable
endif
```

But when I process this in a Makefile.am with automake I get two erros:

```
else without if
endif without if
```

Looks like automake does not digest the ifeq. Is there a way to pass this through it (if it makes sense doing so), or is there another autotools-friendly way of getting the same result?

The idea is also to allow setting/changing the variable just before running make to easily  target different JDKs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## What I think's the right way:

Rely on `$(JAVA_HOME)` being set in `Makefile.am` and make sure a sensible value for it is set by `configure`.

## Answering the Question as Written:

Because `automake` wants to generate Makefiles that work on POSIX make, it doesn't work too well with GNU-make conditionals.

So you do the test in `configure.ac`:

```
AC_SUBST([JAVA_HOME])
AM_CONDITIONAL([JAVA_HOME_SET], [test ! -z "$JAVA_HOME"])
```

Then in Makefile.am:

```
if JAVA_HOME_SET
## Something that relies on JAVA_HOME
else
## Defaults
endif
```