# Canonical way of producing a way of producing a Makefile which varies with the environment using automake

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, automake

I'm struggling to create a Makefile.am which, after being processed, contains a conditional. I've found other questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256609/makefile-conditional-with-automake-autoconf), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368848/checking-environment-variable-in-make-through-automake) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437116/is-there-a-way-to-tell-automake-not-to-interpret-part-of-the-automakefile)) which seem to be struggling to do the same thing. This made me wonder if this actually isn't a sensible goal and there is some other way I should be doing the check.

My goal is to have a Makefile which passes different options to tools based on the environment of the system on which it runs. Crucially I don't want to have to rerun (the lengthy) configure between the different calls to make.

- Is this a sensible goal?
- If not, what is the canonical way of accomplishing the same effect? One way that that comes to mind is adding an additional make target `make check` and `make check-quick` for example.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve. The primary purpose of `configure` is to examine the environment and provide input for the build system (e.g. Automake). After `configure` being run, the system is already examined and unlikely to change, unless you want to move a configured build tree to a different machine, which is risky to be broken anyway.

Comment: The goal is to have a make target which usually runs on a build queue but to give the user an easy way to bypass the queue if it is loaded (say by setting an environment variable like "BUILD=local"). As this is likely to be a transient phenomenon I don't really want to rerun configure to set up local building then run the build and then run configure again to get back building on the queue.